# Javascript Regex not working correctly

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to fetch any string between 'null[' and ']' , but for some long strings its missing immediate ] and printing text till some random ']'
However, If I shorten that string, its working fine,

How can I find out the text till immediate ] and not till some random ']'?

Eg .

"value":"vale0[var0]","null[1st]","value":"vale2[var1]","value":"vale3[var3]"

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Untitled</title>
     <script type="text/javascript">
      function run(){
            code = document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0].innerHTML;
            results = code.match(/null\[(\S*)\","/g);
            for (i=0;i<results.length;i++) {
            value = results[i].match(/null\[(\S*)\","/);
            alert (value[1])
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="run()">
        registerFragment("qweeqeqw","null[country-      name-IR_1]","AI_0_1264":"Anguilla[country-name-AI_18096]</body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Seems like you need [`/null\[([^\s\]]*)]\","/g`](https://regex101.com/r/uNC4FT/1)

Comment: Or https://regex101.com/r/uNC4FT/2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your regex is just a bit incomplete.  If you want the minimum matching characters between two known sequences, add the `?` operator to the `*`.  This will make the `*` operator "non-greedy."

```
null\[(\S*?)\","
```

In this version, however, the closing bracket will be included in the matched group.  If you want to keep the closing bracket out of the match, add that character, as well.  (Here, I've also replace the `\` before the first `"` because it's not necessary to escape the `"`.)

```
null\[(\S*?)]","
```

And, at this point, you don't even need to check for the `","` sequence because the closing `]` should do the job on its own:

```
null\[(\S*?)]
```

[regex101.com example](https://regex101.com/r/V2Rx0t/2)

Comment: " add the ? operator to the *. This will make the * operator "non-greedy." "
Exactly what I was looking for, Thanks !!